# Rails 3 app not working on production env after upgrading twitter-bootstrap-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-rails

Recently I upgraded [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) by removing all the bootstrap assets and reinstalling it. The app now working OK on development mode, but when I publish to heroku it doesn't work and I get the "Something went wrong.." page error. So I guess something is not configured on my end properly for production mode or or I messed up some config while I was trying to fix this error. (i.e. environment settings )

Here is what I get when I run this on production mode locally. I'll also paste in the env [settings here](http://pastie.org/4676929). Can someone please tell me what's not right with the setup?

```
me@home:~/workspace/myappname$ rails s -e production
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

[DEVISE] Devise.apply_schema is deprecated and has no effect. Please remove it.


[DEVISE] Devise.use_salt_as_remember_token is deprecated and has no effect. Please remove it.

DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveAdmin::Dashboard is deprecated and will be removed in the next version
[2012-09-07 00:16:52] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-09-07 00:16:52] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-02-16) [i686-linux]
[2012-09-07 00:16:52] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4774 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-07 00:16:59 +0100
Processing by PhotosController#index as HTML
  Rendered collection (0.0ms)
  Rendered photos/index.html.erb within layouts/application (53.0ms)
Compiled bootstrap_and_overrides.css  (1006ms)  (pid 4774)
Compiled application.css  (1018ms)  (pid 4774)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.erb (5352.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5529ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
  (in /home/me/workspace/myappname/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)):
    8:  <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    9:  <![endif]-->
    10:         <!-- Le styles -->
    11:         <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
    12:         <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    13:         <link href="images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
    14:         <link href="images/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">
  app/views/layouts/_head.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts__head_html_erb___806530288_90965610'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___795323884_92505740'
  app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:8:in `index'
```

Comment: Your error indicates you probably have an `@some_array_thats_nil` being accessed. What variables does `layouts/_head.html.erb` access? Have you tried deleting everything in the templates and slowly adding it back to find the offending code?

Comment: The _head.html.erb doesn't have any data values, only the default application css and js include lines. The rest is just plain html. I also deleted all the markup from my layout files and I still get the same error. I still think this something to do with twitter bootstrap. May be similar to this ? -https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/123

Comment: Looks like it's having a problem with application.css, when you request just this file, do you get the same error?

Comment: I noticed in your production.rb file that `config.assets.compile = true` the default[ http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html ] is usually false, so that might be something to look into.

Comment: @cheeseweasel yeah I think this is something to do with css. I removed all the bootstrap assets from my app now and dev env working fine, but prod env not working. 
@MollyStruve - Well I tried both `true|false` Im so stumped.

Here is what I get http://pastie.org/4678958 when try `bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace`